# If my Termination statement in a for-loop is i < n * n , is my running time then O(n^2)?

Tags: big-o

So im just a bit confused on how to correctly interpret the running time of this for-loop:
for (int i = 0; i < n * n; ++i) {}

I know the basics of O-Notation im just insecure of how to correctly interpret the running time and I couldn't find similar examples.

The problem is actually a triple nested for loop and I know you just multiply the running time of nested loops but this one makes me insecure.

Comment: Did you mean "unsure", not "insecure"?

Comment: _"I couldn't find similar examples"_ With respect, this would be the _second_ example in any text on big-oh notation.

Comment: Yeah unsure im sorry. So actually I've been looking through a lot of pages, and nobody could really provide me final answer

Comment: Which text are you using?

Comment: What do you mean by text ?

Comment: Which book are you using to learn the subject?

Comment: Right now not really one specific book, I have a copy of Cormans Datastructures and Algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

*n* multiplied by itself is *n<sup>2</sup>*, and you perform *n<sup>2</sup>* iterations.

There are no constant factors and no other considerations in this short example.

The complexity is simply *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

Note that this does not consider any hypothetical operations performed *inside* the loop. Also note that, if we take the loop exactly at face value, it doesn't actually do any meaningful work so we *could* say that it has no algorithmic complexity at all. You would need to present a real example to really say.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much. The homework is to examine the running time of some code block and this is just a snippet of it. The whole code block is just some nested for loops with one if- else statement, which I would say runs in O(1) and the loops just perform basic arithmetic to a variable which is O(1) too. And for worst case analytics I would say you just pick the part of the If- else -statement that provides the longer run time to determine the overall running time .